# Does it matter how much you pull out of HTML with Scrapy?

Tags: html, web-scraping, scrapy

I am building a crawler that needs to scrape the entire HTML files, and I was wondering if requesting `response.body` or  `response.body_as_unicode()` would use more server than say, just requesting `response.xpath()` to get more specific part of HTML.

My intuition is that it shouldn't make any difference since the entire HTML page has to be requested regardless of which part you extract, but I just wanted to make sure with users who are more experienced with how `scrapy` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My intuition is that it shouldn't make any difference since the entire HTML page has to be requested regardless of which part you extract

Sure, at the moment you can access the `response` object, the request was already processed and the response was already downloaded.